# Getting the next x elements including a specific one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was using the following jquery code to select the first 10 consecutive elements

```
$(".pag-num-1").nextAll(".num-btn").slice(0, 9).show();
```

The problem was, it wasn't selecting the base element i.e. `.pag-num-1` element, so what I am doing now is manually displaying the element `.pag-num-1` i.e.

```
$(".pag-num-1").nextAll(".num-btn").slice(0, 10).show();
$(".pag-num-1").show();
```

I wasn't able to find another to achieve this.

Is there another way that I can select the base element i.e. `.pag-num-1` element along with the other elements i.e. using the same line in which I have used `nextAll()`? That'd be more cleaner, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [addBack()](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/):

```
$(".pag-num-1").nextAll(".num-btn").addBack().slice(0, 10).show();
```

That will create a new jQuery object consisting of both the results of `nextAll()` and the originally matched elements (`$(".pag-num-1")` in our case).

Note: `addBack()` was named `andSelf()` before jQuery 1.8.